# Number of rectangles with odd side lengths on a chess board?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Given an 8x8 chess board, how do we find the total number of rectangles with odd side lengths?
(Both sides have odd length).

In general, what would be an elegant method to deal with problems like these?

Comment: it will have all 64 rect with odd lengths.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: A rectangle is completely determined by its edges. Choose two of the nine horizontal lines and two of the nine vertical lines, and you’ve defined a rectangle. In how many ways can you choose the two lines so that they’re on odd number of units apart?

Comment: That is exactly what I am having trouble with... For example, If we choose a line in the middle, we will have a large number of possible lines which are at odd distances, but if we choose a line at the top or bottom, we will have fewer options.

Comment: @Quark: Let’s look at the two vertical boundaries. The lefthand one can be in any of $8$ positions. If it’s the left edge of the board, the righthand boundary has to be $1,3,5$, or $7$ cells over; that’s $4$ possibilities. If it’s one cell in, the righthand boundary again has $4$ possibilities. Continue in this fashion. If you stare at it a bit, you should even be able to generalize what happens to larger boards.

Answer (score 4):

The essential point is that the whole situation is a cartesian product!

A rectangle has odd side lengths iff the horizontal and the vertical side lengths are both odd. Therefore you can reduce your problem to the one-dimensional case: Given a stretch of $n$ segments of unit length ($n=8$ in the case of a chessboard), determine the number $N(n)$ of substretchs of odd length.

The number you are looking for is $\bigl(N(8)\bigr)^2$.